# Python: Logical flow for setup and validation

Tags: python, logic

I am having trouble figuring out how to structure the logical flow of my python application's initial setup module.  I have a number of functions that perform small steps in finding that required config files are present, validating them if they are there, creating them if they are not, testing a login with the validated credentials, and finally, if everything checks out, starting the main application.

A simplified list of the functions is below:

```
def config_files_present(config_path):
    config present = is_the_file_there
    return config_present

def validate_config_file(config_file):
    valid_email = code validating email returns True or False
    valid_fqdn = code validating fqdn returns True or False
    valid_config = valid_email is True and valid_fqdn is True
    return valid_config

def write_config(config_path):
    code with user input to collect credentials and write config.ini
    config_file_written = True
    return config_file_written

def test_login(config_file):
    code to login with config_file and 
    return mailbox_object

etc
```

The (simplified) happy path is easier for me to visualize:

```
ready = False
while not ready:
    config_present = config_files_present(config_path)
    if not config_present:
        write_config_file = write_config(config_path)
        if write_config_file:
            valid_config = validate_config_file(config_file)
            if valid_config:
                login_test = test_login(config_file)
                if login_test:
                    ready = True
                    run the main app
```

The complicated path is more complicated. I have mapped out how it should work, but can't figure out how to program it.
[image: flow of functions based on function returns]
Trying to represent the above flow in the `else` clauses of each `if` feels like it will turn into a bottomless recursive spiral.  I suspect that there is probably an established best practice or structure to do this kind  of thing, but I don't know what it is.

Do I power through this recursive mess, or is there a better way to structure this logical flow?

EDIT: Going to close this question.  Because each function has only 1 possible next step if it evaluates to True, I should be able to call the next function in sequence within the function, provided the original logical test evaluates to true.  Then, in my `else` clauses, I will just kick it back to the step that needs to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Going to close this question. Because each function has only 1 possible next step if it evaluates to True, I should be able to call the next function in sequence within the function, provided the original logical test evaluates to true. Then, in my else clauses, I will just kick it back to the step that needs to be repeated.